# jQuery won't clear form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I KNOW this question has been asked numerous times as I have used this website's solutions to no avail. I currently have this implementation:

```
$("input:reset").click(function () {
    $('#answer_2').html('License number is not long enough');
    $('#answer_1').html('');
    $('#data_entry').each (function(){
        this.reset();
    });
});
```

I know the selector is correct as the two html changes (I put them in to confirm I was selector for the reset button click correctly) occur as they should.

Here is my form declaration:

```
<form name="data_entry" id="data_entry" method="post" action="">
```

The problem is I keep getting the error that there is no 'reset' function and the form is never cleared. This is my most recent attempt at following answers to this problem on stackoverflow site. Please help.

Comment: You have duplicate ids on the form?

Comment: Why not use a reset button and code to the onreset event?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa -I tried the method there also, did not work. So, not a duplicate. But, thanks.

Comment: @HenryGeiter No, you tried it wrong. You used the reset inside the each() method and you should not.

Comment: @HanletEscaño It is a reset button - here is the code <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">. Didn't work

Comment: @HenryGeiter and the reset button does not clear the form?

Comment: @PSL - no, all unique ids. But, good thought. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - Could you post corrected format?

Comment: @HenryGeiter Why are you using a `$.each` for a single item in that case?

Comment: @PSL - I am trying to empty all the fields in form data_entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `each` is wrong and it's unnecessary.

```
$('#data_entry').get(0).reset();
```

This should work because you got the right element but `$()` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) will grab your DOM element and then you can use `reset()` (which is not a jQuery function)

Comment: That worked perfect. That is my preferred answer, although @Daryl Gill above did the trick too.

Answer (score 2):

Why reset when you want to clear/empty?

```
this.empty();
```

might do the trick?